# Color resources for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, colors

I'm new to iPhone development and are looking for at way to use color resources (like in Android). I want to apply them on text and panel backgrounds etc.

The ultimate goal is to be able to switch color resources while keeping the code and xib files intact. In this way it shall be possible to for example make several versions of the app with different text colors by just changing the rgb value in one single location.

I know it is possible to switch the image resources in this way, but havent seen anything similar with the colors.

Appreciating any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UIColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is quite amazing.

It has a lot of nice, desirable colors available out of the box. For instance:

```
[UIColor clearColor];
[UIColor redColor];
[UIColor greenColor];
[UIColor blueColor];

[UIColor lightTextColor];
[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

On top of it, you can generate all sorts of nifty things with a little math and some macros. This one lets you generate colors from 8-bit hex values (i.e `0x000000` for black).

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor 
    colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 
    green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
    blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

You can also load a `UIColor` object from an image.

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png]];
```

To use any UIColor object, you can simply do this:

```
UITextField.textColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
```

Just note that the property you're assigning has to be a UIColor property (obviously).

**Edit:** For what you want to do, this may be the best solution:

1. Create a new code file. Call it something like `VJColorConstants`.
2. Do this for each color you want to use:

```
+(UIColor *)prettyColor{
    return UIColorFromRGB(0x4A6B82);
}
```

There are about 100 spins on how to return a constant, but I like that one. After you have that file set up, you can do this:

```
UIView.backgroundColor = [VJColorConstants prettyColor];
```

Comment: Thank you Aurum Aquilla, Since I want to link the color resource rather than defining it in the code the solution accoring to your suggestion would be to read it from an image. This would be achievable if I created a png image for all the colors I want to use. But it seems to be a bit unefficient. Also takes more space than just keeping references to rgb values. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this color resource can only be used from code? If i have a text in the .xib file, how can I access this color from there? It's not possible, is it?

Comment: If you want to change a color in the xib, just use the color picker.... You can drag a color you use a lot into the little squares at the bottom of the picker for use later.

Comment: Yes, but say I have hundreds of xib files with color1 all over and want to change it to color2. Do I really have to go through all of those xib files manually to change the color?

Comment: At that point, I'd probably write a script that changes the Xib's code automatically. It's XML so it's not that hard to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

umm not sure I understand your question properly, but my suggestion would be to take a Global constant for the color. That way you can change it from one particular loacation.

```
#define CUSTOM_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5607 blue:0.8627 alpha:0.50]
```

Comment: Hi BK, This is definitely better than entering the rgb value all over the code. I was hoping to have a file in the resources directory, where the colors were defined. In that way I could link in different sets of resources for different needs but keep the code untouched. A matter of linking so to speak. Thanks.

Comment: yes, if you want predefined colors then u can store in as a array in NSUserDefaults or if ur not bothered about the colors then you can write a Random function and feed the values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is by using #define preprocessor macros. But then you have to set all your colors in code. You have to connect all your views to IBOutlets and so on.

```
#if VERSION_PINK
#define kBackGroundColor [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:105/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:1]
#elif VERSION_GREEN
#define kBackGroundColor [UIColor colorWithRed:155/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:155/255.0f alpha:1]
#else
#define kBackGroundColor [UIColor colorWithRed:150/255.0f green:150/255.0f blue:150/255.0f alpha:1]
#endif

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backGroundColor = kBackGroundColor;
}
```

You would then set VERSION_PINK=1, VERSION_GREEN=1 and so on in the Preprocessor Macros in the build settings of your app.

Comment: Thank you. This is like the comment from BK below but one step more advanced. I will consider this and also try the solution suggested by Aurum Aquila to read the color from a png image. BR// Vanja